# Function Call in a java web application in a different JVM

Tags: java, web-applications, process, runtime

I want to call a local function in a web application using Process Builder or Runtime class. But i am unable to figure out. Is there a way out.Basically i have a jsp and I am calling a class and from that class i have to call a method in another class in a different JVM for three times passing three different parameters. So it will run in three different JVMs for each parameter. How should I do it?

Comment: As how I understand your question, you don't want to call a classes method inside another, `already living` jvm. You want to create a jvm per call, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a JAR with the driver class containing the function which i want to call. And call that jar passing three different arguments using process builder. Its not the exact solution. I wanted the same functionality without creating a JAR i.e directly call the function or the driver class in process builder passing the arguments thrice separately. But as of now i am following this approach. Hope somebody finds the exact solution for this